# Why is changing from Debug to Release slow in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I work on a fairly complex project in visual studio. Whenever I need to change configuration from Debug to Release, it takes up to 20 seconds for the change to take effect. What is VS doing meanwhile that justifies this long wait time?

NB: I have a good SSD drive and enough RAM to be sure that the bottleneck isn't in the hardware.

Comment: Do you have a UWP project in the solution?

Comment: No I don't have it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Visual Studio only uses one thread when switching from `Debug` to `Release` mode...